# Inserting a string formatted datetime into my db has lead me to this error. Any solutions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, phpmyadmin, pymysql

The script is reading the strings right, but it can't seem to progress and insert into the db.

This is for a home project of mine. I'm using a RasPi 3 ModelB+.

```
a = input('Scan Card: ')
now = datetime.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

#This is the insert line
tapped = "INSERT INTO log (rfid, taptime) VALUES (%s, %s)" %(a, now)
t = conn.cursor()
t.execute(tapped)
conn.commit()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "door.py", line 54, in <module>
    t.execute(tapped)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':40:44)' at line 1")
```

I just want a log db of the cards tapped.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use string substitution, but pass the values as parameters in execute:

```
tapped = "INSERT INTO log (rfid, taptime) VALUES (%s, %s)")
t = conn.cursor()
t.execute(tapped, (a, now))
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but the error is here

now = datetime.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

the problem is that you are using H , M and S.
Try: date("Y-m-d H:i:s") where numeric values are being used

You must be doing thi for a 24-hours format.

Comment: Not the case
    print (now)
results to
    21:17:42.883302

thanks for the reply

Comment: Did it helped to any extent ? @Reksi

Comment: No. Sorry the syntax is correct, it was just the strings were not in parameters